# Equal height constraints issue iOS Interface builder

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, constraints

I have four UILabel in a Row. Label's title is changing dynamically based on some conditions. Title may be multiline or single line. So all the labels should maintain same height means height of the Max height label. I added Equal height constraints for all labels using storyboard, But issue is suppose one Label have multi line it simply neglects the height and shows only one line, if two labels have multi line all the labels maintain the multi line height and shows correctly. I tried different constraints combinations but result is same, Maintain height only if two of them have bigger heights.

Answer (score 0):

remove Height and Equal Height Constrain.
Just add Constrain from Top,Bottom,Left Right except Last label.
in last label Add Left,Right and Height Constrain
and use number of line will zero to all Label :)

Comment: I tried it, We can't set height constraints. We need Equal height constraints. If we set height constraints how we dynamically set the height using storyboard and also how other labels maintain the last label height?

Answer (score 0):

Got a new idea. After u set equal heights change the compress / hugging priority ( higher value means harder to change )

Comment: If u want u can put them in a horizontal stack view. Horizontal stack view makes sure you labels have the same height..

Comment: Yes.. now i put labels in horizontal stack view but same effect, If one is muti line, remaining three neglects it. If two is multiline remaining two accepts it and maintain height